# Is there anyway to avoid regex function differentiating between special caracters in a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to scrape the string between an `<a>...</a>` box, from an html file. I'm using regex with a pattern that could identify the links.

I have tried to find an appropriate regex pattern for that: `((/+\w+)+([:.]?(\w+))?(.org)?)(\W\w+)+`. And I have written the code to scrape the links I need.

For these lines stored in a document:

```
<div class="portal" role="navigation" id='p-navigation'>
<h3>Navigation</h3>
<div class="body">
<ul>
 <li id="n-mainpage-description"><a href="/wiki/Main_Page" title="Visit the main page [z]" accesskey="z">Main page</a></li>
 <li id="n-contents"><a href="/wiki/Portal:Contents" title="Guides to browsing Wikipedia">Contents</a></li>
 <li id="n-featuredcontent"><a href="/wiki/Portal:Featured_content" title="Featured content  the best of Wikipedia">Featured content</a></li>
<li id="n-currentevents"><a href="/wiki/Portal:Current_events" title="Find background information on current events">Current events</a></li>
<li id="n-randompage"><a href="/wiki/Special:Random" title="Load a random article [x]" accesskey="x">Random article</a></li>
<li id="n-sitesupport"><a href="//donate.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FundraiserRedirector?utm_source=donate&utm_medium=sidebar&utm_campaign=C13_en.wikipedia.org&uselang=en" title="Support us">Donate to Wikipedia</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```py
def find_link():
    links = re.findall(r"((/+\w+)+([:.]?(\w+))?(.org)?)(\W\w+)+")
    return links

for link in links:
    print(link)
```

I expected the output to be a link in each newline, but not:

```
('/wiki', '/wiki', '', '', '', '/Main_Page')
('/wiki/Portal', '/Portal', '', '', '', ':Contents')
('/wiki/Portal', '/Portal', '', '', '', ':Featured_content')
('/wiki/Portal', '/Portal', '', '', '', ':Current_events')
('/wiki/Special', '/Special', '', '', '', ':Random')
('//donate.wikimedia.org', '//donate', '.wikimedia', 'wikimedia', '.org', '=en')
```

Comment: Your approach to this is odd. If you're searching for links, why not just capture the `href`s per your example? Secondly, most people will recommend BeautifulSoup (a library I'm not a fan of). But, yea, why are you not using the hrefs, now? Third, you're code snippet will produce an error.

Comment: 1.I have found a regex path to approach the links through the `href`, here's my path `href="([\W]+[\w./:?=&]+)`. 
2.Excuse my lack of knowledge, I would like to know what's wrong with my snippet.